# an evidence finding

Tags: probability, fuzzy-logic

could anyone help me to solve this? I am not able to think where to start this..please help and give hints
Rain causes bus failure. The bus failure causes Anil and Hari to be absent.

P(Anil absent when bus fails)=0.3
P(Anil absent when bus does not fail)=0.2 
P(Hari absent when bus fails)=0.3
 P(Hari absent when bus does not fail)=0.2 
P(Bus fails on a rainy day)=0.4
P(Bus fails on a non rainy day)=0.1
Today Anil is absent but Hari is present. What is evidence for rain?

Comment: I will say a wet coat.

Comment: this is better than original...

Comment: If it rains $100$ times, how often do you expect the bust to fail, and so how often do you expect Anil to be absent but Hari to be present? If it does not rain $100$ times, how often do you expect the bust to fail, and so how often do you expect Anil to be absent but Hari to be present?